# Self-built C# Library not found

Tags: c#, dll

I have an issue including a self-built library to a C#-project. I have created an own class library called ClassLibrary1 just to learn how to add libraries on Visual Studio 2019.

So I have written some simple code in a newly created .NET-class library project and have clicked on "create new solution" (directly translated from my german IDE-language. Maybe it's called slightly different) after writing the code. Back in the C#-project, I have selected the dll-file from bin/Debug/ of the class library's project folder.

After I have set the checkmark, the dll-file was shown in the solution-explorer under Assemblys like expected. But the issue I now have is that I still cannot use the ClassLibrary1.dll-file in the cs-file in this very project as I expected via the command "using ClassLibrary1;". It only shows me the error message "type- or namespacename "ClassLibrary1" not found" when trying to compile the C#-project and I don't get, why this is the case.

It seems like it has to be a very obvious problem but after some research on the internet and trying some things by myself still nothing has changed.
Thanks in advance for helpful replies.

Comment: Here is Fahrzeug.cs from ClassLibrary1:

using System.ComponentModel;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
 public partial class Fahrzeug : Component
 {
  public Fahrzeug()
  {
   InitializeComponent();
  }

  public Fahrzeug(IContainer container)
        {
   container.Add(this);

   InitializeComponent();
        }

  private int geschwindigkeit;

  public string ausgabe()
        {
   return "Gesschwindigkeit: " + geschwindigkeit;
        }

  public void beschleunigen(int wert)
        {
   geschwindigkeit += wert;
        }
 }
}

Comment: And here is Program.cs from the target project:

using System;
using ClassLibrary1;


namespace Übung_18
{
    
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            
        }
    }
}

Comment: The projects are in different solutions, so I think it theoretically works the way I tried it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The by far easiest way to manage a library is to use project references. Ensure that your library and the project that uses the library is in the same solution. Then right click the "references" and select "add Reference", go to the project tab and add a checkbox for the library. [Read more about managing references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-references-in-a-project?view=vs-2019).

You might also need to add namespaces for the classes you wish to use in the source files.

I would not recommend managing using file-references to lose dll-files, since it can easily become a hassle to manage. I.e. if you create a new version of the library you would need to build, and explicitly replace this file in all other projects and update all the references.

If you want to share libraries between multiple solutions the more popular solution would be to setup a [nuget server](https://adamtheautomator.com/nuget-server/). This solves some of the updating problems by maintaining multiple versions of the same library, and provides a nice interface to update references in all projects. But this is a somewhat more complicated solution, so I would not recommend this for new developers.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. That really helped me a lot to understand how to work with libraries.